# Can I safely reference a NETMF project in a normal .NET Framework app?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

I have a solution with a .NET Micro Framework 4.3 project and a .NET Framework 4.5 project. When I reference the former in the latter one I get a warning:

> *The project cannot be referenced. The referenced project is targeted to a different framework family (.NETMicroFramework)*

However, my initial tests show that everything works fine. I can use classes from the micro project in the full-framework one. The solution builds and runs without problems.

Are there any limitations to this? What are the consequences? In what circumstances such referencing could cause compile or runtime errors?

Answer (score 1):

.NET Micro Framework and .NET Framework binaries are different. They target different platforms even though some classes and use of methods looks identical. Solution for you will be to create *Shared Project*. Unfortunately it is available only in MSVS 2015.

Comment: Do you mean that my simple tests turning out okay is pure luck and the behavior of (nearly) any instruction calling the micro framework is undetermined?

Comment: I did not understood you. You have a unit tests, or you copied .NET Micro Framework classess and pasted in .NET Framework class library project?

Comment: I have a unit test project in .NET Framework 4.5 which tests a NETMF 4.3 class library project. The tests pass. I did not copied any code between the projects.